# Combine two queries with different 'FROM' tables but similar 'JOIN' tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries that I'm trying to combine into one result set.

Query 1:

```
SELECT t1.evalID, t2.[Order], COUNT(t2.StepID) AS 'Total Categories'
FROM Evals t1
JOIN Steps t2 ON t1.TemplateID = t2.TemplateID 
JOIN GradingCats t3 ON t2.StepID = t3.StepID 
GROUP BY t1.EvalID, t2.[Order]
ORDER BY t2.[Order]
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT t4.EvaluatorID, t6.StepID, t6.[Order], COUNT(t4.Grade) AS 'Grades Entered'
FROM Grading t4
JOIN GradingCats t5 ON t4.GradingCatID = t5.GradingCatID 
JOIN Steps t6 ON t5.StepID = t6.StepID
GROUP BY t6.StepID, t4.EvaluatorID, t6.[Order]
```

My end goal is to locate which steps of an evaluation have missing grades.

edit (sample data):
Query #1

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      evalID         |     Order        |  Total Categories   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          81         |      01.00       |         17          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          81         |      02.00       |         17          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          81         |      03.00       |         17          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Query #2

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     evaluatorID     |       Step       |        Order        |   Grades Entered |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|        1178         |        609       |        01.00        |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|        1178         |        615       |        02.00        |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|        9441         |        609       |        01.00        |        17        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|        9441         |        609       |        02.00        |        17        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|        9441         |        609       |        03.00        |        17        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: This isn't as simple as a `UNION ALL` is it? Sample data and desired results might help here if not.

Comment: On a different note, I suggest getting out of the habit of using aliases like `t1`, `t2`, ...`t6` sooner rather than later: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: You need to have similar columns (data types and count. And do a union all between queries.

Comment: Not so sure this is a UNION.   Sounds more like an OUTER JOIN, but that's a guess based on the last sentence in the question.   Without sample data and desired results, the question isn't clear enough to answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman
Correct...I've tried a UNION. 
I have also tried a few OUTER JOIN as well, but obviously not the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the first query which shows all the steps associated with an EVAL, you can LEFT OUTER JOIN the second query, and the steps that are NULL on the right side of the query will be the ones that are missing grades.

In order to do this, there must be some way in your tables to link `Grading` to `Evals`.  This column is not evident from the code you posted, but I will assume it is there.   Maybe it's through `GradingCats`.

In shortened psuedo-code, just to show what I mean:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Evals e
INNER JOIN Steps s ON e.TemplateID = s.TemplateID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grading g ON g.EvalID = e.EvalID  --use whatever means you have to show which Eval a Grade is from
LEFT OUTER JOIN Steps gs ON {join to Grading through GradingCats as in your second query}
WHERE gs.StepID IS NULL
```

In analyzing the result of this query, all the Steps of every Eval will be in `s.StepID`, and when the same row has a NULL for `gs.StepID`, that means that step did not get a grade.

Note that you won't want to do any GROUP BY in this query, since you want a row-level analysis.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker (with more knowledge of the data than I) slightly modified my query:

```
SELECT query1.stepID, Categories, Graded
FROM
(
    SELECT rs.stepid, COUNT(c.category) AS 'Categories'
    FROM Evals e
    JOIN RunScriptSteps rs ON e.TemplateID = rs.TemplateID
    JOIN GradingCats c ON rs.StepID = c.StepID
    WHERE EvalID = *(someNumber)*
    GROUP BY rs.stepid
)AS query1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT s.StepID, COUNT(Grade) AS 'Graded'
    FROM Grading g
    JOIN GradingCats c ON g.GradingCatID = c.GradingCatID
    JOIN Steps s ON c.StepID = s.StepID
    WHERE EvalID = *(someNumber)*
    GROUP BY s.stepid
) AS query2
ON query1.stepid = query2.stepid
ORDER BY stepid ASC
```